# Render looks way too bright in both viewport and render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting, color, color-management

I have to render a video where a bottle crashes onto the ground.
I managed to render half the video on a PC at my school, but I had to go home so I stopped the render and decided to render the missing frames on my own laptop from home. I don't remember changing any particular settings, but on my laptop the render looks way different to what I got from my school PC.
The colors look desaturated, and the whites look overexposed, in both Cycles and Eevee, and the viewport and the render. The lights in the scene also seem to be the exact same. I've heard people say that messing with the color management settings would help, but that does pretty much nothing for me.
I'll provide a picture of a frame rendered on my school PC next to the same frame but from my laptop so you can see the difference in lighting and colors.
I don't know how I can share my scene on this website since I'm new here, but if you need it I can try to find a way.
Thanks for helping ! [image]

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com given code copy paste via edit into your Question ... or any other way (retransfer or what ever if it is a big).

Comment: This isn’t a strong comparison. One is from the render viewport inside of Blender, and the other is from a separate program reading the final file. Even if they were both final renders instead of one being a preview render, they could still look different because of the video player’s color settings or just how it’s programmed.

Comment: By another words you should compare both rendered images (PC/laptop) in player app or blender app ...